# is pjsip_endpt_handle_events necessary for pjsip timer

Tags: c++, voip, pjsip, dtmf

i'm using pjsip 2.01  in debian linux. i'm writing small class to allow my program make calls to specific phones and play wav files. i already did that and everything works fine. but now i want to play DTMF signals inside the call. i want to use timer to play DTMF after 5 seconds of all. so i'm looking on
pj_timer_entry_init 
pj_timer_heap_schedule
i found few samples. but they are a bit controversial.
some of them are using threads and pjsip_endpt_handle_events 
another don't
currently i don't use threads in my program, though i'm making 3-4 calls simultaneously.
so the quesion is - do i need to use pjsip_endpt_handle_events in separate thread for timers to work properly?

Comment: trying pjsip_endpt_schedule_timer now, questions remains the same. should i use pjsit_endpt_handle_events for it to work correctly.
may be it will be clear after some testing